# Aliens in "The Abyss" directly responsible for loss of life?

Tags: movie, the-abyss

I could be wrong in my understanding or interpretation of the movie "The Abyss", but ultimately, it is the aliens cause the crash of the USS Montana, and more importantly, the death of the entire crew.

However, this is completely ignored in the film, even in the extended version. I also have yet to see any mention of this anywhere. The aliens exhibit a good understanding of our technology and as such would not be blind to the fact that their technology disrupts our own, and in the film, negatively so. They could have prevented the crash, their power over matter/elements, clear to see.

Arguably, a downed submarine makes a good launching pad for many of the plots in the film, and stunning footage. But still, there didn't need to be a downed submarine to begin with.

I'd appreciate some explanation or insight on why the crew had to die, aside from making a great plot line.

Comment: Bheku, do either of these answers work for you?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Initially, I found both answers to be speculative, but I'll go with Sredni's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the extended version the aliens are causing the tsunami that could have killed many innocent humans on the coastline. Only when they realize Virgil had sacrificed his life to "save" them, they change their minds.

In the [FAQs on IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096754/faq?ref_=tt_faq_1#.2.1.3) you can read:

> "A very elaborate ending was indeed scripted and filmed for the
>   theatrical version of The Abyss. It starts off after Bud is saved by
>   the aliens. They show him the news on a giant video wall about the
>   imminent war between the USA and the Soviet Union. This changes into a
>   special report about giant tidal waves that appear everywhere around
>   the globe, threatening all mankind. Bud instantly understands that the
>   aliens are responsible for these tsunamis, and he asks why they want
>   to destroy mankind. They respond by showing him images of the many
>   wars and atrocities committed by humans in their seemingly
>   never-ending route to self-destruction. But, as the waves are about to
>   hit the land, they stop and retreat; the aliens have stopped them.
>   Bud's sacrifice has showed them that humanity may have the strength
>   and wisdom to make it after all. The movie then ends with the
>   spaceship rising up towards the ocean surface."

So, having a sub full of sterotypically obtuse war-mongering military go down because they tried to track (and possibily attack) one of their vessels is in line with their "plan".

The plan being, I guess: "let's kill them all before they kill each other".

Jokes aside, alien thinking can be open to wide speculations. Like: they were trying to warn US and URSS by killing a few hundred thousand people in order to save hundreds of millions from a nuclear war; or, they wanted the ocean for themselves and did not want to share the planet with a hopeless warmongering species. 
From the discussion about the movie emerges that:

> According to the novelization, they were planning on exterminating us
>   for the good of the planet. We were looked on as an out-of-control
>   species that threatened all life on the planet. They decided to have
>   some final up-close studies of Humans before they went ahead and
>   that's when they had their close encounters with the crew of the
>   Benthic Explorer, with Bud's deactivation of the nuke as final proof
>   to them that we weren't all crazy and deserved a second chance.

The real-life reason appears to be that the sub sinking is in line with the original plot, but becomes hard to explain when they cut out the tsunami scene for length reason.

Comment: +1 for "alien thinking can be open to wide speculations".

Comment: That's not an uncommon theme in sci-fi movies. The Day the Earth Stood Still was all about the alien coming and essentially telling humanity "if you don't stop what you're doing, we're going to wipe you out before you can spread your violent ways beyond your own planet" or "we're going to save your planet by removing humanity". So many movies since then have repeated that theme

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR: The Montana was "attacked" for being too close to the alien vessel.**

---

The [**aliens**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Abyss) most likely buzzed the USS Montana because they perceived it as a threat to themselves. After all, the submarine was practically on top of their vessel, and loaded to the teeth with nuclear weaponry. Whether or not they knew the scout would disrupt human electronics is debatable, but either way the action is still justified by the alien point-of-view.

From the aliens' perspective, there are several events which convince them that Earthlings are a violent & barbaric race:

- A "warship" carrying nuclear weapons is "shot down" near the alien vessel.
- Another vessel (the Deep Core rig) arrives at the top of the trench and parks there.
- Shortly after the rig arrives, a large mass of machinery drops down into the trench.
- Attempts to communicate via the water probe are met with aggression.
- The rig has at least one nuclear weapon aboard, a weapon which is later sent down the trench.
- Monitoring of global events shows widespread warfare & violence everywhere.

Although the aliens had probably seen potential in the crew of the Deep Core, it wasn't until they witnessed the dialogue between Bud & Lindsey that they understood the concept of love, or that humans understood the concept.

**Up until that point, humanity was simply a violent pest that needed to be removed from an otherwise useful (inhabitable) planet.**